# header and need to extend underline because border-bottom not useful in my case

Tags: header, underline

I would like to have an underline under my header, with the width of a bottom-border to put it simple. 
However, I did not find how to extend the width/length of my underline.

Pay attention: in my case I cannot use a borderbottom. This solution does not work in my case.

```
 <h1 id="hcomp"><img src="exp.png"/>Comp</h1>
```

The only solution would be to add spaces until i reach the width of my page:

```
 <h1 id="hcomp"><img src="exp.png"/>Comp                                
                        </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
<h1 id="hcomp"><img src="exp.png"/>Comp <hr class="hrstyle"></h1>
```

Css :

```
   .hrstyle
{
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(114, 159, 207);  
    margin-left: 0.6cm;
    margin-top:0.05cm;
    border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: none;


}
```